# swift drag drop tableviewcontroller

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, drag-and-drop

Before I've just used `tableView.setEditing(true, animated: true)` in order to make rows in tableView move. I used the code:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canMoveRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
return true
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath) {
array.insert(array.remove(at: sourceIndexPath.row), at: destinationIndexPath.row)
}
```

I've found that there is an interesting protocols: `UITableViewDragDelegate` and `UITableViewDropDelegate`. I have to implement 2 funcs and add `tableView.dragDelegate = self; tableView.dropDelegate = self; tableView.dragInteractionEnabled = true`

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, itemsForBeginning session: UIDragSession, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UIDragItem] {
return []
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, performDropWith coordinator: UITableViewDropCoordinator) {
}
```

What is surprising to me is that this code is enough to make rows move. And I have a simple question - is it that simple? May be I miss something, may be I have to add something?

Comment: Everything is stored in 'array' and it gets modificated in 'moveRowAt' after I move the row...